# TFS WorkItemLinkTypes no LinkTypeEnds

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I try to add a Link between my Task and my UserStory. 
The Program works on my LocalPC, but on the Server the execution fails, 
because the `workItemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds` are empty.
Whats the problem on the server ?

```
    private static void CreateNewWorkitem(...)
    {
    using (var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://SERVER URI")))
             {
                var workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tpc);
                var teamProject = workItemStore.Projects["PROJECT"];
                var workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Fehler"];

                WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
                { Title = Titel, IterationPath = Path };
                ...
                try
                {
                  workItemStore.RefreshCache(true);
                  WorkItem Task = userStory.Copy(teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Aufgabe"]);
                  Task.Save();
                  userStory.Links.Add(new RelatedLink
                  (workItemStore.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds
                  .First(k => k.Name == "Untergeordnet"),Task.Id));                        
                  userStory.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Fehler! " + e.ToString());
            }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the same TFS server?

Comment: I tried to connect from the TFS server to the TFS Server and also from another Windows Server. In both cases the LinkTypeEnds were null. Only on my local pc the WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds are filled.

Comment: Which versions of TF dlls are you using? Do you local pc and server have exactly same version(s) of VS installed?

Comment: Same Version of dlls and same VS Version Installed.
When i execute the executable .exe on my local pc it works on the server it fails.

Comment: @dertrautmann, agree with ds19, maybe you're connecting to a different TFS server. Also try to modify your code of second line to be "      using (var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection")))      "